# as3 error Property serverInfo not found on String and there is no default value

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm currently experimenting AMFPHP with ActionScript 3, and everything is going fine but I get the following error when I'm inserting data into my database, but the data will insert into my db.

Below the code in PHP first:

```
<?php 
public function setColor($kleur){
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO kleuren (kleuren) VALUES ("'.$kleuren."')");
  return $kleur;
?>
```

Ignore the security issues for now I'm up to date for SQL injections but that is not important for now.

My AS3 code looks like below:

```
import fl.controls.Button;
import fl.events.ComponentEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.net.NetConnection;
import flash.net.Responder;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;
import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

/**

MidasSerialComm 2.6.1

Attributes
    input
        a value which receives from serial port.

Methods
    serIn()
        Returns a String value read from serial port.
    serOut(String arg)
        Send "arg" to serial port.
        No return value.

*/

// The belows are parameters for configuration of module
midas.commport="COM4"; // necessary field
//midas.baudrate="9600";;
//midas.parity="n";
//midas.databit="8";
//midas.stopbit="1";
//midas.eof="ascii 13";
//midas.stx="null";
//midas.etx="null";
//midas.debug=false;
midas.serverip="localhost"; // necessary field
midas.serverport="8864"; // necessary field

midas.visible = false;

//knoppen rood , groen en blauw opzetten

var roodLampje:Sprite = new Sprite();
roodLampje.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
roodLampje.graphics.drawRect(stage.stageWidth / 2 + -150, stage.stageHeight / 2, 60, 40);
roodLampje.buttonMode = true;
addChild(roodLampje);

var groenLampje:Sprite = new Sprite();
groenLampje.graphics.beginFill(0x00FF00);
groenLampje.graphics.drawRect(stage.stageWidth / 2 + -80, stage.stageHeight / 2, 60, 40);
groenLampje.buttonMode = true;
addChild(groenLampje);

var blauwLampje:Sprite = new Sprite();
blauwLampje.graphics.beginFill(0x0000FF);
blauwLampje.graphics.drawRect(stage.stageWidth / 2 + -10, stage.stageHeight / 2, 60, 40);
blauwLampje.buttonMode = true;
addChild(blauwLampje);


var zetLampjeUit:Sprite = new Sprite();
zetLampjeUit.graphics.beginFill(0x000000);
zetLampjeUit.graphics.drawRect(stage.stageWidth / 2 + 60, stage.stageHeight / 2, 60, 40);
zetLampjeUit.buttonMode = true;
addChild(zetLampjeUit);

//kleuren 

var rood:String = "Rood";
var groen:String = "Groen";
var blauw:String = "Blauw";

var huidigKleur:String;
var netConnection:NetConnection;
var responder:Responder;

//click events toevoegen aan buttons
roodLampje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onRoodClick);
groenLampje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onGroenClick);
blauwLampje.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onBlauwClick);
zetLampjeUit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onUitClick);

//connectie met service
netConnection = new NetConnection();
netConnection.connect("http://navidmirzaie.com/amfphp/gateway.php");
responder = new Responder(onResult, onFault);


var t:TextField;
var textFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",14,0x000000);


midas.ondata = function(msg){


    switch(msg){
        case "49":
            huidigKleur = rood;
            netConnection.call("ArduinoTest.setColor",responder,huidigKleur);
            //trace(huidigKleur);
        break;

        case "50":
            huidigKleur = groen;
            netConnection.call("ArduinoTest.setColor",responder,huidigKleur);
            //trace(huidigKleur);
        break;

        case "51":
            huidigKleur = blauw;
            netConnection.call("ArduinoTest.setColor",responder,huidigKleur);
            //trace(huidigKleur);
        break;

        case "48":

        break;

    }   


}


//click handlers, reageer op de gedrukte knop
function onRoodClick(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
    midas.output("1");
    //trace("er is op rood geklik");
}

function onGroenClick(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
    midas.output("2");
    //trace("er is op groen geklik");
}

function onBlauwClick(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
    midas.output("3");
    //trace("er is op blauw geklik");
}

function onUitClick(eventObj:MouseEvent):void {
    midas.output("0");
    //trace("er is op blauw geklik");
}

//data afhandeling post
function onResult(responds:Object){

    var t:Array = new Array();
    t = responds.serverInfo.initialData;
    //var t:Array = responds.serverInfo.initialData;
    trace(t.length);

    /*
    for(var i:uint = 0; i < t.length; i++){
        trace("Aantal "+t[i][0]+" "+t[i][1]);
    }
    */
}

function onFault(responds:Object){
    for(var i in responds){
        trace(responds[i]);
    }
}


netConnection.call("ArduinoTest.getCountofTotallColors",responder);
//data ophalen van arduino
```

I get this error:

> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property `serverInfo` not found on `String` and there is no default value. at test2_fla::MainTimeline/onResult()

I don't get the point of the error and thats the reason I can't debug my code.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, you receive an unclassified string in your response. Do a debug on what type of Object you've been passed in your onResult() function like this:

```
function onResult(responds:Object):void
{
    if (responds is Array) {
        trace('Array has been received:',responds);
        // do something with that array
    } else if (responds is String) {
        trace('String has been received:',responds);
        // do something with that string
    } else {
        trace('An object of unknown type has been received:',responds);
        for (var i:String in responds) trace('['+i+']',responds[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: i get the following in my output window.


An object of unknown type has been received: [object Object]
[serverInfo] [object Object]

Comment: i just don't get the problem, everythings working fine.. i can get the amount of each color and the value of the colors are inserting succesfully in my database, i don't get where the error came from.

Comment: Well, if there was finally an object with "serverInfo" property received, everything is yet fine. But that time you might have been hit with either an incomplete received data or an unexpected answer of a wrong type, and that threw an exception you witnessed. I'd advise you testing like this every time you receive a response, just in case something accidental would happen, and you won't end up with a thrown exception.